# Separate Numerical Values Based On Pattern Match

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I need to separate 100s values from 90 values... `sed` may not be the best way to do accomplish this but regardless, I am trying to separate 90s from 100s by inserting a space between the two numbers.

**Code:**

```
sed 's/1[0-9][0-9]/ 1[0-9][0-9]/g' file
```

**Data File:**

```
99100 93 96 95 94 93 96 98100
```

**Current Result:**

```
99 1[0-9][0-9] 93 96 95 94 93 96 98 1[0-9][0-9]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
99 100 93 96 95 94 93 96 98 100
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is "backreference".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace with `&`, the whole match:

```
s='99100 93 96 95 94 93 96 98100'
echo $s | sed 's/1[0-9][0-9]/ &/g'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ATuFFI), result: `99 100 93 96 95 94 93 96 98 100`.

See [`sed` reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions#index-Parenthesized-substrings):

> Also, the replacement can contain unescaped `&` characters which reference the whole matched portion of the pattern space.

Comment: To avoid matching `1000`s and longer, you would need *word boundaries*, and e.g. something like `sed 's/\B1[0-9][0-9]\b/ &/g'` (GNU `sed` supports this pattern). Or you will have to use some more groupings/backreferences.

Answer (score 1):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='9[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]' '{ r=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) r=r FS $i; print r }' file
```

The output:

```
99 100 93 96 95 94 93 96 98 100
```

---

- `-v FPAT='9[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]'` - pattern defining field value (90s or 100s)
- `r=$1` - capturing the 1st field as initial field
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through the remaining fields